# How to catch specific ExecuteError in Python?

Tags: python, error-handling, try-except

I am getting a specific error in one of my scripts:

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 000229: Cannot open F:\path\to\file.tif
```

I have isolated these instances using a try/except block:

```
try:
    #Do something

except:
    #Do something in the event of failure
```

How can I trap the specific ExecuteError described above within the `except` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of hacky but if you want to catch 000229 only you could do something like this:

```
try:
    # your code
except ExecuteError as err:
    if str(err.message).startswith("ERROR 000229"):
        # do something
    else:
        # do something else
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. But you can check the various attributes of the exception object to see if it's the one you care about, and reraise the exception otherwise.

```
try:
   ...
except ExecuteError as e:
  if not can_handle(e):
    raise
  handle(e)
```